# DocuSign - API - GetTemplate

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new to the DocuSign API. I'm learning and trying to understand how it works.

So I started by creating a dev account.

Then I try to create a Template and follow this steps:

1. Login to app.docusign.com
2. Click on Templates
3. Click on 'Create Template' button.
4. Upload template
5. Fill  Template Name and Description
6. Add Recipients to the Envelope (My self)
7. Next
8. Add few fields
9. Save and Close

Using postman I was able to reach the login_information endpoint and get the baseUrl to send my requests.

[login_information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYK0.png)

After that I get the templateId from the site and try to get the template:

[templateId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lUzV.png)

[template request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un9cl.png)

As you can see I get that the envalope does not exist.

So after that I assume that I have to create an envelope with that template. So I create a request for that:

[create envalope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezb3A.png)

This is the jason I'm sending on the body:

```
 {

  "emailSubject":"This is a DocuSign Test from Mauricio",

  "status":"sent",

  "templateId":"22981491-ba7c-4411-880e-87a9b5b3afd8",

  "templateRoles":[
    {

      "email":"mtaranto@test123.com",

      "name":"Mauricio Taranto",

      "roleName":"test",

      "routingOrder":"1",
    }

  ],

  }
```

The problem is that it seems that the API can't find the template.

What am I'm doing wrong?

I changed the Shared property of the template. And select OWNER, Administrators, **Everyone**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause here is that the template exists in the Production environment (which you're accessing via app.docusign.com), but when using Postman you're hitting the Demo environment.

If you log in via https://demo.docusign.net and create a template there, you should be able to access it through the API.

Comment: Hi Drew! Thanks! I didn't noticed that! I woks now! thanks!